# Javascript and css files truncating in browser response from tomcat server

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tomcat, web-applications

Some of the Javascript and css files are truncating in browser response, happens in chrome, firefox and opera as well.

My custom.js file is of 20KB size with 634 lines of code
Browser console shows:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

[image]

P.S. I have set the follwing parameters in tomcat but to no avail

server.xml

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" 
   maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
   maxThreads="150"
   minSpareThreads="25"
   maxSpareThreads="75"
   enableLookups="false"
   acceptCount="100"
   disableUploadTimeout="true"
   maxPostSize="0"/>
```

web.xml

```
<multipart-config>
  <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
  <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
  <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

Truncated file in browser messes up the web page layout, is there any option in tomcat server or any web browser to load my file complete without its code being truncated no matter if the file is large?

One more observation, there are larger files in my code(almost 45 KB) that are being loaded fine, without being truncated.

Also I have compressed the custom.js file, its now 13KB but in browser its showing same and error same as in case of uncompressed file.

Comment: If you look in the browser dev tools, does it show any more information? E.g. was the response closed unexpectedly, or did it complete OK but with truncated data? Is there anything in your server log? You're probably not hitting the 52MB file limit shown there - something else is happening here.

Comment: @Tim Perry Its returning with 200 Success code, nothing closes unexpectedly

Comment: This symptom can occur when loading large web applications (> 1000 files), when the maximum number of open file descriptors per process is only 1024. In that case, increase it before starting the browser: ulimit -n 4096.